# How to go from Frankfurt am Main Intl Airport to the center of Darmstadt on train

Tags: trains, frankfurt

What is the most convenient way to go from Frankfurt am Main Intl Airport to the center of Darmstadt on train?

RMV's website states there are couples way of doing this (S-Bahn, RE, etc.)  However, other online materials suggests mutually contradictory things: the website of the conference I will go to in Darmstadt mentions the use of S-Bahn, while a previous city-dweller's web page states S-Bahn is time-consuming and recommends RE.

I am looking forward to see answers from people with first-hand experiences.

Comment: There are busses too, apparently… Otherwise you need a connection. By definition the S-Bahn stops more but at the end of the day, Darmstadt is not very far and the difference isn't going to be huge. You should simply look up the schedule and take the next train.

Comment: Incidentally, reports based on first-hand experience and your conference's website are likely to be based just as much on what's easier to explain/what people were able to figure out than on the rather minute differences in transit time. The bus, on the other hand, is in fact much faster.

Comment: You wrote: "**I will go to in Darmstadt mentions the use of S-Bahn, while a previous city-dweller's web page states S-Bahn is time-consuming**". These are not contradictory, both are true. You go to Frankfurt Hbf and transfer to the S-Bahn and it takes a long time to reach Darmstadt on the S-Bahn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on exactly when you are going to travel. There is a bus taking 25 minutes from Frankfurt Airport to Darmstadt Hbf (central station), but since the bus usually only departs once an hour you might be sooner in Darmstadt if you use a train connection or bus/train combination via Mainz, Neu Isenburg or Frankfurt Hbf (some 45 to 60 minutes).

You can find suitable connections on the German Railways' [homepage](http://www.bahn.de).

Answer (score 3):

[S-Bahn](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:S-Bahn_Berlin_Baureihe_481.jpg) is an urban commuter train, most stops are just a few kilometres apart. Typically they depart every 10 or 20 minutes, depending on the line and the time of day.

[RE](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:101_029_MNE.jpg) is a regional commuter train, often stops are a few dozen kilometres apart. Typically they depart every 30 or 60 minutes.

The RE will be faster, but not if you have to wait for it. The S-Bahn might require you to get several connections, which can be inconvenient for foreign travelers.